# Regular expressions (RegEx) to filter string from URLs in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I want to filter a string from the URLs in Google Analytics. This can be done using the Views > Filter > Exclude using RegEx, but I have been unable to get it to work.

An outline of how these filters are set up, can be found [here](https://getfishtank.ca/blog/regular-expression-google-analytics-filters), however, I can not work out how to isolate the string using RegEx. I believe it will need to be one filter per URL type.

The URLs follow this format:

```
/software/11F372288FA/pagename
/software/13F412C5FA/pagename/summary
/software/XIL1P0BFXCKM81/pagename2
```

I need to exclude this part of the URL:

```
/11F372288FA/
```

So that the URL data (e.g. Session time) is recorded against:

```
/software/pagename
/software/pagename/summary
/software/pagename2
```

I have worked out that I can isolate the string using thing following RegEx

```
^\/validate\/(..........)\/accounts\/summary$
```

It is not very elegant and would require a filter for every URL type.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain if this will work in your exact case but instead of using regex for this it might be easier to just create a new string from the start to the end of "software" and append everything from pagename to the end. In Java this might look something like:

```
String newString = oldString.substring(0, 9) + oldString.substring(oldString.indexOf("pagename"));
```

Take note though that this will only work if the "software" at the start is always the same length and you are actually only excluding things between "software" and "pagename".